# searching string in list

Tags: python, file-io

I have file that contains couple lines of text.
I open the file this way in my code:

```
final = codecs.open("info", 'r', 'utf-8')
lines = final.readlines()
```

then I want to find exact lines:

```
if 'Edytuj'.join('\n') in lines:
#rest of code
```

I know the file contains `'Edytuj'` but that statement is always `False`, am I making mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at what `'Edytuj'.join('\n')` returns?  (it returns `'\n'` since you're joining an iterable of length 1).  I'm guessing that's not what you meant to do.

What exactly do you want that test to do?

Maybe you meant:

```
if any('Edytuj' in line for line in lines):
   pass #...
```

or possibly:

```
if 'Edytuj\n' in lines:
```

Comment: I want to check if `lines` contains "Edytuj" string

Comment: `lines` is a list.  Basically, for that test to be True, you'd need "Edytuj" to be on a line all to itself, and you might need to append a newline on the end of `"Edytuj"` -- e.g. `"Edytuj\n"` (I can't remember if `.readlines()` leaves the newline on the end of the lines or not right now..

Comment: I thought that `in` statement do that for me :p
I'm new in Python, still learning

Comment: Or possibly `if "Edytuj\n" in lines` since he seems to want perfect matches only.

Comment: `"foo" in "this foo"` will return `True`.  `"foo" in ["this foo"]` will return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with codecs.open("info", 'r', 'utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if u'Edytuj\n' == line: # match full line
           #rest of code
```

You could use `if u'Edytuj' in line` if there may be other content in the line.